# Expressjs is returning json instead of html

Tags: node.js, express, template-engine

I am developing a simple web app using [kiwi](https://github.com/coolony/kiwi) templating engine and [express](http://expressjs.com). When I open my app in browser, template is correctly generated and everything but the result is JSON encoded.
I tried setting res.type('html') but this only seems to change mime sent by application. I am not using any AJAX requests yet.

I have following code:

```
"use strict";

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var publicDir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/view');
    app.engine('kiwi', require('kiwi').__express);
    app.set('view engine', 'kiwi');

    app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: publicDir }));
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.static(publicDir));
});
app.configure('development', function(){
    app.use(express.logger());
});


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {title: 'kiwi'});
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

I use layout file like this (removed most of layout html for readability):

```
<div class="container">
    {{block content}}{{/block}}
</div>
```

This is index.kiwi file:

```
{{extend 'layout'}}
{{block content}}
<p>Hi ${title}</p>
{{/block}}
```

This is what I see in browser (sent with text/json mime):

```
"<div class=\"container\">\n\t\n<p>Hi kiwi</p>\n\n</div>"
```

How can I make it to send normal HTML?

**UPDATE:** OK, I managed to find [another app](https://github.com/mavdi/olivia) similar to mine (using both express and kiwi) and only difference I found was library versions. So I downloaded express 3.0.0beta7 and it's working. Weird huh?

**UPDATE2:** The bug is between 3.0.0rc4 (html output) and 3.0.0rc5 (json output)

**UPDATE3:** I believe that only changes that could be relevant are commits [40be3ed05d](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/commit/40be3ed05d75e631d175cf63ad28897b4eff141d) and [9eb1da4568](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/commit/9eb1da4568bc5b6811fec5679e61e4a332e9122f) both changing connect version or maybe [8edf358739](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/commit/8edf358739447e259616adc474fc17c3e8e9dcff)

You can see the repo here: https://github.com/jtojnar/srs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW (read your edits, just sharing ;): I recently checked out Kiwi templates and ran into the same issue.

My fix at the time was this:

```
  this.engine('kiwi', function(filename, options, callback) {
    kiwi.__express(filename, options, function(err, rendered) {
      if (! is_production && err)
        console.error(err);
      callback(err, rendered.toString());
    });
  });
```

The `rendered` argument wasn't a string, but an object. That confuses Express and makes (or rather: made) it return JSON instead. Didn't give me a whole lot of confidence in Kiwi, in the end I went for [swig](http://paularmstrong.github.com/swig/) instead.

Comment: Weird behaviour. Thanks I'll use this for now and consider switching to another template engine.

Comment: It looks like it was fixed on github repo 5 months ago([commit d09bb91fbe](https://github.com/coolony/kiwi/commit/d09bb91fbe7c41f1a109a29b7176695c4d2eeebb)) but wasn't moved to npm.